# Isaacs Character Theory exercise 6.4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, characters

Studying character theory of finite groups using Martin Isaacs' book "Character Theory of Finite Groups", I came across the following problem (exercise 6.4):

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $\mathscr{H}(G) = \{H \subset G \mid \exists \psi \in \operatorname{Irr}(H) \text{ such that } \psi{\uparrow}^G \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)\}$. Consider $\mathbb{H}(G) = \bigcap \mathscr{H}(G)$. Prove that, if $G$ is an $M$-group (that is, if every irreducible character of $G$ is induced by a linear character of a subgroup), then $\mathbb{H}(G)$ is abelian.

This is one of those problems where I don't really know how to proceed. I believe the easiest way to go about this is probably to show that every irreducible character of $\mathbb{H}(G)$ is linear. So let $\psi$ be one such character, and write $$\psi{\uparrow}^G = \sum_{i=1}^t a_i\chi_i$$

as a combination of irreducible constituents, where $a_i \in \mathbb{N}^*$. Computing both sides at $1$ yields $[G: \mathbb{H}(G)]\psi(1) \leq [G: \mathbb{H}(G)] \sum_{i=1}^t a_i$, where we used the fact that $G$ is an $M$-group to express each $\chi_i$ as a character induced from a linear character of a subgroup, and used the fact that said subgroup contains $\mathbb{H}(G)$. This means $\psi(1)$ is bounded by the number of irreducible constituents that appear in the decomposition of $\psi{\uparrow}^G$.

This is pretty much where I get stuck. I think Clifford's Theorem probably plays a role somewhere, but I couldn't extract any meaningful information using it... My main difficulty is that I know next to nothing about the characters of $\mathbb{H}(G)$ besides the property I proved above...

Is this a good approach? If so, how do I continue? And, if not, how to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Does the characteristic subgroup $\mathbb{H}(G)$ defined above have a name? I couldn't find anything about it elsewhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Theorem** Define $\mathscr{H}(G)=\{H \leq G: \varphi^G \in Irr(G) \text{ for some } \varphi \in Irr(H)\}$. Put $H(G)=\bigcap_{H \in \mathscr{H}(G)}H$. Then the following hold.
$(a)$ $Z(G) \subseteq H(G)$
$(b)$ If $G$ is an $M$-group, then $H(G)$ is abelian
$(c)$ If $G$ is solvable, then $H(G)$ is nilpotent of class $\leq 2$ (in other words $H(G)' \subseteq Z(H(G)))$.

**Proof** In the sequel, CTFG is the book *[Character Theory of Finite Groups](https://www.cefns.nau.edu/%7Efalk/classes/511/Isaacs_Character_theory.pdf)* of I.M. Isaacs. The theorem combines the solutions to Problems (6.4) and (6.5) from that book.

(a) Let $\varphi \in Irr(H)$ with $\chi=\varphi^G \in Irr(G)$. Then (see also similarly (5.11)Lemma, CTFG), $Z(\chi)=core_G(Z(\varphi)) \subseteq H$, hence (see also (2.28)Corollary, CTFG) $Z(G) \subseteq Z(\chi) \subseteq H$ for each $H \in \mathscr{H}$. This proves (a).

(b) Observe first that $H(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ (this follows from (6.1)Lemma in CTFG), so $[H(G),H(G)]$, being characteristic in $H(G)$, is normal in $G$. Now assume $G$ to be monomial and let $\chi \in Irr(G)$, and $\chi=\lambda^G$ for some linear $\lambda \in Irr(H)$, $H \leq G$. Again (5.11)Lemma from CTFG asserts that $ker(\chi)=core_G(ker(\lambda))$, is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$. Now $H(G) \subseteq H$, so $H(G)' \subseteq H' \subseteq ker(\lambda)$, since $\lambda$ is linear. But $H(G)' \unlhd G$, so we must have $H(G)' \subseteq ker(\chi)$. However (see (2.21)Lemma in CTFG), $\cap_{\chi \in Irr(G)}ker(\chi)=1$, so $H(G)'=1$, that is, $H(G)$ is abelian.

(c) Let $N \unlhd G$ and $\varphi \in Irr(N)$. Clifford's Theorem yields $I_G(\varphi) \in \mathscr{H}(G)$. So $H(G) \subseteq I_G(\varphi)$, hence $\varphi$ is $H(G)$-invariant. Let $h \in H(G)$ and $n \in N$ and $\lambda \in Irr(N)$ a linear character. Then $\lambda(hnh^{-1}n^{-1})=\lambda^h(n)\lambda(n^{-1})=1$. So $[H(G),N] \subseteq ker(\lambda)$ for any linear $\lambda \in Irr(N)$, whence $\color{blue}{[H(G),N] \subseteq N' \text{ for any } N \unlhd G}$. Recall from (b) that $H(G)' \unlhd G$, hence plugging this into the blue formula we get $\gamma_3(H(G)) \subseteq H(G)'' \subseteq G''$. With induction one gets: $\gamma_{k+1}(H(G)) \subseteq G^{(k)}$. Hence, if $G$ is solvable, $H(G)$ must be nilpotent.

Finally, in general, if $X$ is a nilpotent group of class $k \geq 3$, then the lower central series looks like this:  $\gamma_{k+1}(X)=1 \lt \gamma_{k}(X) \lt \gamma_{k-1}(X) \lt \cdots \lt X$ and $[\gamma_{k-1}(X),\gamma_{k-1}(X)] \subseteq \gamma_{2k-2}(X)$ (see for example D.J.S. Robinson, *A Course in the Theory of Groups*, 5.1.11(a)). But $\gamma_{2k-2}(X)=1$, since $2k-2 \geq k+1$. Hence $\gamma_{k-1}(X)$ is an abelian characteristic *non-central* (since $1 \lt \gamma_k(X)=[\gamma_{k-1}(X),X]$), subgroup of $X$. 
So, if $H(G)$ would have a nilpotency class $\geq 3$, then the formula in blue would give $[H(G),\gamma_{k-1}(H(G)]=1$, whence $\gamma_{k-1}(H(G))$ centralizes $H(G)$, a contradiction. We conclude that $H(G)' \subseteq Z(H(G))$.$\square$

Comment: You should add at least one more argument to the proof of (b).

Comment: Added, thanks, see what you mean.

Comment: @NickyHekster, thank you for your very complete answer! Would you happen to know if $H(G)$ has a name?

Comment: @Gauss, no never seen $H(G)$ in any paper. You could ask Marty Isaacs himself ... isaacs@math.wisc.edu

Answer (score 3):

First we prove that $\textbf H(G)\vartriangleleft G$. We take $H\in\mathscr H(G)$ and $g\in G$. Then then it suffices to check that $H^g\in\mathscr H(G)$. If $\varphi\in\text{Irr}(H)$ then the class function $\varphi^g(h^g)=\varphi(h)$ is an irreducible character of $H^g$. If $\varphi^G\in\text{Irr}(G)$ we shall prove that $(\varphi^g)^G\in\text{Irr}(G)$, or equivalently,
$$[((\varphi^g)^G)_{H^g},\varphi^g]=[(\varphi^g)^G,(\varphi^g)^G]=[\varphi^G,\varphi^G]=[(\varphi^G)_H,\varphi].$$
It holds that
$$|H^g|[((\varphi^g)^G)_{H^g},\varphi^g]=\sum_{h\in H}(\varphi^g)^G(h^g)\overline{\varphi^g(h^g)}=\sum_{h\in H}\frac{1}{|H^g|}\sum_{x\in G}\dot{\varphi^g}(h^{gx^{-1}})\overline{\varphi(h)}=$$
$$\sum_{h\in H}\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{x\in G}\dot{\varphi^g}(h^{xg})\overline{\varphi(h)}=\sum_{h\in H}\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{x\in G}\dot{\varphi}(h^x)\overline{\varphi(h)}=\sum_{h\in H}\varphi^G(h)\overline{\varphi(h)}=|H|[(\varphi^G)_H,\varphi].$$
Then $\textbf H(G)$ is normal in $G$. 
Now we take $\lambda\in\text{Irr}(\textbf H(G))$ and an irreducible constituent $\theta$ of $\lambda^G$. Since $G$ is an $M$-group we may write $\theta=\alpha^G$ for some linear character $\alpha$ of a subgroup $H$ of $G$. Thus $\textbf H(G)\subseteq H$. Now,
$$0\not=[\theta,\lambda^G]=[\theta_{\textbf H(G)},\lambda]=[(\alpha^G)_{\textbf H(G)}, \lambda].$$
Furthermore, since $0\not=[\alpha^G,\alpha^G]=[(\alpha^G)_H,\alpha]$ it follows that $[(\alpha^G)_{\textbf H(G)},\alpha_{\textbf H(G)}]$ is nonzero and hence $\alpha_{\textbf H(G)}$ is an irreducible constituent of $(\alpha^G)_{\textbf H(G)}$, as is $\lambda$. By the normality of $\textbf H(G)$, from Clifford's theorem we conclude that $\lambda$ and $\alpha_{\textbf H(G)}$ are $G$-conjugated characters and therefore $\lambda$ is a linear character. Then $\textbf H(G)$ is abelian.